# Is the server running on host "db" (172.28.0.2) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? Docker

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker

django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "db" (172.28.0.2) and accepting  TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

docker-compose

version: '3.9'

```
services:
  backend:
    build: ./backend
    command: sh -c "python manage.py migrate && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/app/backend
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    env_file:
      - backend/.env.dev
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:14-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    env_file:
      - backend/.env.dev
volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9.10-alpine

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
WORKDIR /app/backend
COPY requirements.txt /app/backend
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN apk add --update --no-cache postgresql-client
RUN apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .tmp-build-deps \
      gcc libc-dev linux-headers postgresql-dev
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN apk del .tmp-build-deps 

EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["python3", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

Database setting:

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
        "NAME": os.environ.get("POSTGRES_DB"),
        "USER": os.environ.get("POSTGRES_USER"),
        "PASSWORD": os.environ.get("POSTGRES_PASSWORD"),
        "HOST": os.environ.get("POSTGRES_HOST"),
        "PORT": 5432,
    }
}
```

.env :

```
POSTGRES_USER=user
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
POSTGRES_DB=my_db
POSTGRES_HOST=db
```

Comment: I think you still need to add `db` under backend [`links`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#links)

Comment: Does your Django app connect to the database on startup? `depends_on` only waits until the container is started, so if you connect immediately, Postgres won't be ready to accept connections.

Comment: so it starts from db

Answer (score 1):

Use [docker-compose networks](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#networks)

`docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: 3.9

services:
  backend:
    build: ./backend
    command: sh -c "python manage.py migrate && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/app/backend
    networks:
      - backend
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    env_file:
      - backend/.env.dev
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:14-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - backend
    env_file:
      - backend/.env.dev
volumes:
  postgres_data:

networks:
  backend:
     driver: bridge
```

I added `network`. see [this link](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#networks)

I guess it work.

Comment: Nothing changed. To resolve this issue I have to run docker-compose up more than 1 time with or without networks. I suppose that because  backend try to connect db before  db is starting.

Comment: I guess you should use `wait-for` in docker compose. it's a script that waits for container running
https://medium.com/@krishnaregmi/wait-for-it-docker-compose-f0bac30f3357

Comment: thanks , but I got a new issue after adding script in Dockerfile                                   failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: "/wait-for-it.sh" not found: not found

Comment: Can you send your dockerfile again?

Comment: just added : COPY wait-for-it.sh wait-for-it.sh 
                     RUN chmod +x wait-for-it.sh

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue. I was using docker version 20.10.12 and then upgraded docker-compose to v2.4.1. After restarting my system the build was working fine.

Answer (score -1):

Are you running Django on your local machine or inside of the docker?

If you're trying to run it on your local machine, just use `localhost` instead of the container name `db` for your `POSTGRES_HOST` env variable.

But, I'm not sure about the exact reason. Can you share the logs via `docker logs backend` and `docker logs db`?

Comment: the setup clearly indicates use of docker-compose

Comment: inside docker.  docker logs backend:
    
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "db" (172.28.0.2) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Comment: Please share your Postgres logs. @tarp20

Comment: starting PostgreSQL 14.2 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 10.3.1_git20211027) 10.3.1 20211027, 64-bit
  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
 listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
 listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
 database system was shut down at 
  database system is ready to accept connections
  received fast shutdown request
 aborting any active transactions
 background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 56) exited with exit code 1
 shutting down
  database system is shut down

Comment: Your postgres container has failed. That's the reason. Try to delete current containers and reconfigure your docker-compose file. I didn't use this alpine version before. But maybe changing image version can help. Because I can't see any other issues on your compose file.

Comment: There might be a typo. - `postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/` update this line to `- ./postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/` @tarp20

Comment: You can run the Django project separately on your local machine. Sometimes I do exact same when I'm developing a new project. There is no much information to have an idea about what is happening. That is why I needed to make sure. But thanks anyway. @Marat

Comment: logs says that problem in backend